# Using VBA in Excel Macro to print an existing pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a function check if a .pdf file exists. If it exists I want to print the file.

```
    Function PrintPDF(PartNum As String)
    Dim DirFile As String
    DirFile = "\\SERVER5\hpfiles\Company\Drawings\PDF-SL8\" & PartNum & ".pdf"
        If Dir(DirFile) = "" Then
    Exit Function
    Else
    DirFile.PrintOut

    End If
    End Function
```

I get a compile error saying Invalid Qualifier. I assume its because DirFile is a string.

How do I use this string as the targeted file for printing?

Answer (score 0):

Correct, you can't print a string.  One way is to use a shell command and print the file like this:

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function apiShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, _
ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
As Long

Public Sub PrintFile(ByVal strPathAndFilename As String)
    Call apiShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "print", strPathAndFilename, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
End Sub

Function PrintPDF(PartNum As String)
    Dim DirFile As String
    DirFile = "\\SERVER5\hpfiles\Company\Drawings\PDF-SL8\" & PartNum & ".pdf"

    If Dir(DirFile) = "" Then Exit Function

    PrintFile (DirFile)
End Function
```

Adapted from [this post](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=146904)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great!  Assuming this does it for you please mark as answered.  Cheers